# Django 1.11 - Query to exclude based on other table

Tags: django, django-models

## Problem

I'm trying to build a system to invite people to teams so I have Team and Invitation models. I'm trying to query users that don't have a team and that aren't in the Invitations table with that team. So far I can filter the users that don't have a team but I can't figure out how to exclude users that already have an invite from that team.

## What I have so far

```
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector

sv = SearchVector('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
team = parsed_body['team_id']
query = parsed_body['query']
users = User.objects.annotate(search=sv).filter(search=query, profile__team=None)
```

## Team Model

```
from django.db import models

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=False, default=None)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=512, blank=False, default=None)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

## Invitation Model

```
from django.db import models

class Invitation(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shifter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
User.objects.exclude(invitation__team=1)
```

Where **`1`** is the **`PK/ID`** of the **`Team`** instance you want to specify

Comment: I didn't know that I needed to accept. I'm new to this. Thanks for helping :D

Answer (score 1):

```
User.objects.filter(profile__team=None).exclude(invitation_set__team=your_team_to_exclude)
```

Comment: I'm getting an error. Do you know what it could be?  
`django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'invitation_set' into field. Choices are: contest, date_joined, email, first_name, groups, id, invitation, is_active....`

Comment: `invitation_set` is the [related name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), pointing from the user to all its invitation instances. Did you specify `ìnvitation` another name? Try: `User.objects.filter(profile__team=None).exclude(invitation__team=your_team_to_exclude)`

Comment: It worked, idk why it's not needed set after invitation. Do you know why?

Comment: No, because if not explicitly given otherwise, Django automatically creates a related name [`FOO_set`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects), where FOO is the model class name, `Invitation` in your case, hence `invitation_set`